# Outcome space of 3 biased coins

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a somewhat simple probability question that I'm struggling with:

Consider 3 biased coins (each with probability 75% of landing on heads) that will be flipped only once.

1. What's the outcome space:
2. What's the size of the event space:

My understanding for outcome space is that if there are 2 outcomes for each coin it's $2×2×2=8$

{HHH}, {HHT}, {HTT}, {HTH}, {THH}, {TTH}, {THT}, {TTT}

My guess for the event space is that if I'm flipping 3 coins only once, that's 3^8 = 6,561

These answers aren't affected by bias coins right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the outcome space and the size of the event space are not affected by the bias of the coins, unless at least one of the coins is biased in a way that makes it deterministic (i.e. probability of heads is either $0$ or $1$).

The event space is not as large as you have calculated.  Although you are correct that the number of elementary outcomes is $8$, the number of distinct events that we can enumerate from the set of outcomes is equal to the size of its **power set**; that is to say, $2^8$.  We can see this by assigning an indicator variable to each elementary outcome, which denotes whether that outcome is a member of a given event; then each possible event is uniquely determined by an $8$-bit binary number whose bits encode whether outcome $i$ is a member of that event.

Comment: Is "outcome space" limited to outcomes that have a nonzero probability of occurring? If so, I should probably (with nonzero probability...) modify my answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra In the case of discrete and finite outcomes (i.e., $|\Omega| < \infty$), any elementary outcome with probability zero is not very interesting to consider.  For example, one could define for a single coin toss $$\Omega = \{H, T, \text{duck}\},$$ but the probability of obtaining a duck when you flip a coin is zero (well, unless you're Canadian I suppose).  You could add as many nonsensical outcomes as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

An outcome space can indeed be the collection of these eight strings, and the probability mass for each outcome does not affect their count. $$\cal\Big\{\{HHH\}, \{HHT\}, \{HTT\}, \{HTH\}, \{THH\}, \{TTH\}, \{THT\}, \{TTT\}\Big\}$$

The largest event space is the collection of all subsets of this outcome space : ie the power set.

How big is the powerset of a set of eight atoms?

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified the outcome space (also called the sample space).  An *event* is any *subset* of the outcome space, so the *event space* is the set of all subsets, of which there are $2^8$.

In general, if a set $S$ has $|S|$ elements, then the set of all subsets of $S$, often called the *power set* of $S$, has $2^{|S|}$ elements.